# import class from rt.jar without replacing the rt.jar of running java version

Tags: java

I need to import a class to an external rt.jar in my java code but i'm afraid that this will try to import it of my running version of java or the custom rt.jar replace all the rt.jar of running version.

In fact I need to import only one class, is there a solution to do this ?

I need to replace this code to import the class of the external rt.jar (the idea is to import this missing class in java 8 from java 7)

```
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        }
```

Comment: This driver has been removed for good reasons. Why don't you use a real JDBC driver for your database? And do you really think that this class is all you need?

Comment: I don't use real jdbc driver because this throw a lot of error, i need to maintain the code and review each query will take to many time.I think this is the only class but i'm not sure, it's why i will try it.

Comment: It's quite contradictory to adopt the newest Java 8 version and to keep using a driver that should not be used for years and years.

Comment: I make this to prevent an unexpected update of java by someone else, this will make crash the programs who need to run every night.

Comment: You are mistaken. This is not the only class, by a long chalk. You won't solve the stated oriblem this way.

Comment: This annoy me, i will find an other way to solve that. But for learning purpose is there a solution to do this kind of action ?